# Installing winasio on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: wine

I have installed Wine on Kubuntu 16.04 (64-bit), but I am not able to install winasio, neither via playonlinux nor by compiling it. make returns the following message:

```
make: *** No rule to make target "asio.h" necessary for "all". Stop.
```

I have installed wine-development (apt install wine-development), but it did not help. What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

first you need to install

```
apt install g++-multilib
```

to create 32bit programs.
Also you need the wine development packe:

```
apt install wine-dev
apt install libjack-dev
```

Download the ASIO SDK from http://www.steinberg.net/de/company/developer.html
and you need to download and install libjack-jackd2-0_1.9.8~dfsg.1-1ubuntu1_i386.deb
Make sure that

```
sudo ln -s /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libjack.so.0.1.0 /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libjack.so
```

is done.
from http://packages.ubuntu.com/de/precise/i386/libjack-jackd2-0/download
Edit the Makefile and add pth to ASIOSDK whereever asio.h resists:

```
INCLUDE_PATH --> -I ../ASIOSDK2.3/common/
```

And remove "asio.h" from Makefile in line "all:"

without compiling you need to follow the steps here:
https://lkubuntu.wordpress.com/2014/01/09/how-to-set-up-wineasio/

to use apt:

```
apt search wineasio
Sorting... Done
Full Text Search... Done
wineasio/stable 0.9.0+git20110613-2kxstudio1 amd64
  Wine ASIO driver for JACK

wineasio-amd64/stable,now 0.9.0+git20110613-2kxstudio3 amd64 [installed]
  Wine ASIO driver for JACK (64bit)

wineasio-i386/stable,now 0.9.0+git20110613-2kxstudio3 i386 [installed]
  Wine ASIO driver for JACK (32bit)
```

And then you can use "apt" to install the required winasio package.

Comment: Thank for the comprehensive answer. I got a bit further, but when attempting to install libjack-jackd2-0_1.9.8~dfsg.1-1ubuntu1_i386.deb i run unto a compabillity probleb, beacuse I have JACK2 (jackdmp 1.9.11 installed. I read somewhere that wineasio is compatible with JACK2, but perhaps my version is too new?  What does this package actually contain?

Comment: what source of wineasio you try to compile ? I was working with wineasio-0.9.2.tar.gz from https://sourceforge.net/projects/wineasio/
my host is a Ubuntu 16 server installation as a VM. so maybe this different to your installation. " What does this package actually contain? "-question is related to what package please ?

Comment: It is wineasio-0.9.2.tar.gz and my VM is Kubuntu 16.04, so it seems that we are on the same OS. The packet I was inquiring about is jackd2-0_1.9.8~dfsg.1-1ubuntu1_i386.deb, as it looks like it might be some incompatibility here. The error message I get is (its a french installation):

Comment: The error message I get is (its a french installation): 
gcc -c -I. -I/usr/include -I/usr/include -I/usr/include/wine -I/usr/include/wine/windows    -m32 -g -O2 -D__WINESRC__ -D_REENTRANT -fPIC -Wall -pipe -fno-strict-aliasing -Wdeclaration-after-statement -Wwrite-strings -Wpointer-arith -o asio.o asio.c
asio.c:39:23: fatal error: jack/jack.h: Aucun fichier ou dossier de ce type
compilation terminated.
Makefile:81 : la recette pour la cible « asio.o » a échouée
make: *** [asio.o] Erreur 1

Comment: I did a recording (text-log) of the complete worksession  to build the wineasio-lib. you can download the log here:http://true-informatics.de/compil1-2.log (with also all my mistakes/outputs :-) the is no edit done on this session log.
with "grep apt compil1-2.log |grep install" you can get all the needed package install steps. You see that the install of "libjack-jackd2-0_1.9.8~dfsg.1-1ubuntu1_i386.deb" is working and you need this for the 32bit libjack.

Comment: ...
this shows every step I did. You can download the Makefile here: http://true-informatics.de/Makefile.wineasio and rename it or make a diff to the original Makefile one to see the changes. I hope you can now reply all step to compile the lib now.

Answer (score -1):

**Here is my 64-bit solution**

Install pre-requirements

```
sudo apt install apt-transport-https software-properties-common wget libglibmm-2.4-1v5
```

Install kxstudio (library pack for jackd, wineasio and other useful stuff)

```
wget https://launchpad.net/~kxstudio-debian/+archive/kxstudio/+files/kxstudio-repos_9.4.6~kxstudio1_all.deb 
sudo dpkg -i kxstudio-repos_9.4.6~kxstudio1_all.deb
wget https://launchpad.net/~kxstudio-debian/+archive/kxstudio/+files/kxstudio-repos-gcc5_9.4.6~kxstudio1_all.deb
sudo dpkg -i kxstudio-repos-gcc5_9.4.6~kxstudio1_all.deb
sudo apt update
sudo apt install wineasio cadence
```

Add user to "audio group".

```
sudo addgroup `whoami` audio
sudo reboot
```

Register wineasio

```
wine64 regsvr32 wineasio.dll
```

A bit of configuration

```
cadence
```

- Go to System -> Configure -> Driver -> ALSA -> Device/Interface (pick your audio device)
- Run jack i.e. System -> Start

Now you can run you wine application and WineASIO drivers should be available as audio device (works in REAPER for e.g.)